# retrieving SQL DATETIME and putting it to a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

```
DateTime budget_date=new DateTime();

cmd.CommantText="SELECT * FROM dummy";
cmd.Connection=connection
MySqlDataReader=myDataReader=cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(myDataReader.Read())
{
   //gives an error "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
   budget_date=Convert.ToDateTime(myDataReader["Budget_Date"]);
}
```

Can anyone help me how to get the date to my variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for null.

```
DateTime? budgetDate;

var ordinal = myDataReader.GetOrdinal("Budget_Date");

var value = myDataReader.GetMySqlDateTime(ordinal);

if(!value.IsValidDateTime && value.IsNull)
{
    budgetDate = null;
}
else if(value.IsValidDateTime)
{
    budgetDate = value.GetDateTime();
}
else
{
    // Error with data
}
```

See:

- [`MySqlDataReader`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html)
- [`MySqlDateTime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-types-mysqldatetime.html)

Comment: @_@ sorry sir im a major newbie when it comes to c#

it says "The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string,out system.datetime)' has some invalid arguments

cannot convert from 'out System.DateTime? to out System.DateTime

Comment: var value=myDataReader["Budget_Date"]; // Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DatTime @_@